# Transition not smooth when hover state is removed

Tags: css, sass

So I've created a transition for when a person hovers over an image. This causes the text to appear from the bottom, which is working smoothly. However, when I remove my mouse and the hover state is taken away the text quickly jars back to an opaque state which ruins the effect.

I've created a codepen for this. Hover over the image to see what I mean. http://codepen.io/acha5066/pen/bNxyob

Here is my sass: (I'm using Compass)

```
$grey: #eaeaea;

.content {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content-header {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
.content-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  @include transition(all 1s ease);
  @include opacity(0);
  background-color: rgba($grey, 0.8);
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
   .link {
    border-top: 1px solid darken($grey, 20%);
  }
}

.content:hover {
   .content-main {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: darken(rgba($grey, 0.8), 20%);
    @include opacity(1);
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
  } 
}
```

*UPDATE* As requested compiled CSS

```
.content {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content-header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.8);
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-main .link {
  border-top: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}

.content:hover .content-main {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.8);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This is a pure CSS problem, not a Sass problem, so only provide the compiled CSS.

Comment: PS @chap, of course you can post your SCSS/SASS. Your codepen example was perfect, you don't need to provide compiled CSS as an addition to already provided SASS/SCSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwyqvY)

So if you remove the `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` set on `.content-main`, as it made the text collapse when you moused out. Here the text fades in and out

```
$grey: #eaeaea;

.content {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  @include transition(all 1s ease);
}

.content-header {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
.content-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  @include transition(all 1s ease);
  @include opacity(0);
  background-color: rgba($grey, 0.8);
   .link {
    border-top: 1px solid darken($grey, 20%);
  }
}

.content:hover {
   .content-main {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: darken(rgba($grey, 0.8), 20%);
    @include opacity(1);
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
  } 
}
```